# Need help finding a formula for this sequence: 52, 103, 155, ...

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, integer-sequences

Need help finding a formula for this sequence:

$ A(n) = 52, 103, 155, 206, 258, 309, 368, 412, 463, 515, 566, 618, 669, 747, 772,  823,  875,  926,  978, 1029, 1103, 1132, 1183, 1235, 1286, 1338, 1389, 1494, 1492, 1543, 1595, 1646, 1698, 1749, 1838, 1852, 1903, 1955, 2006, 2058, 2109, 2291, ...$

Is there a single formula that can give this sequence, ideally as a non-recursive polynomial? If so, what is it?

### Details of the sequence

The above sequence is $A(n) = B(60n)$ for $n > 0$ where $B(x) = x - floor(\frac{x}{y})$ and where $y$ is the least non-divisor of $x$. Note that $B(x)$ is the [OEIS sequence A213634](https://oeis.org/A213634); you may refer to [this lookup table](https://oeis.org/A213634/b213634.txt) for mapping $x$ up to $10,000$.

Where I'm getting stuck is that I'm not sure how to represent $y$ (the least non-divisor of $x$) with a standard mathematical equation. On a computer, we can find the least non-divisor of $x$ using a looping function such as the one given in the OEIS page for the sequence of least non-divisors, [A007978](https://oeis.org/A007978):

```
def a(n):
    k = 2
    while not n%k: k += 1
    return k

print([a(n) for n in range(1, 101)])
```

Interestingly the sequence of least non-divisors exhibits striking fractal symmetry based on $a(n) = lcm(1,2,...,x)$ where $x$ is the $n$-th prime power ([OEIS A000961](https://oeis.org/A000961)), [though I'm not sure why](https://www.reddit.com/r/askmath/comments/ydlhbr/why_is_the_sequence_of_least_nondivisors/).

### Properties & patterns in the sequence

I've found some bizarre properties and patterns in this sequence $A(n)$.

The subsequence $Ae(n) = A(2n) = 103, 206, 309, ...$ initially seems to be given by $103n$. This holds for n < 7, but but:

- for $Ae(n)$ from 1 thru 6, we have $103n = ((n-1)+\frac{103}{103})103$
- for $Ae(7)$, we have $747 = 103n+26 = ((n-1)+\frac{129}{103})103$
- for $Ae(n)$ from 8 thru 13, we have $103n-1 = ((n-1)+\frac{102}{103})103$
- for $Ae(14)$, we have $1494 = (103n-1)+53 = ((n-1)+\frac{155}{103})103$
- for $Ae(n)$ from 15 thru 20, we have $103n-2 = ((n-1)+\frac{101}{103})103$
- for $Ae(21)$, we have $2291 = (103n-2)+130 = ((n-1)+\frac{231}{103})103$
- for $Ae(n)$ from 22 thru 27, we have $103n-3 = ((n-1)+\frac{100}{103})103$
- for $Ae(28)$, we have $2987 = (103n-3)+106 = ((n-1)+\frac{206}{103})103$
- for $Ae(n)$ from 29 thru 34, we have $103n-4 = ((n-1)+\frac{99}{103})103$
- for $Ae(35)$, we have $3734 = (103n-4)+133 = ((n-1)+\frac{232}{103})103)$

Clearly therefore we might have some term like $-floor(\frac{n}{14}-1)$ in the equation, but I'm not sure how to account for the additional $26, 52, 130, 106, 133, ...$ that gets tacked onto every 14th member of the sequence.

Any help would be appreciated, I feel at this point I'm seeing the trees and not the forest. Thanks.

### Update, 3/9/23

I discovered that this sequence appears to be based on the sequence $a(n)=\{52,103,155,206,258,309,361,412,463,515,566,618,669,721,772,...\}$ defined by the recurrence relation $a(n+8)=-a(n)+a(n+1)+a(n+7)$, which can be defined non-recursively as:

- $a(n)=51\lfloor\frac{n}{7}\rfloor +51\lfloor\frac{n+1}{7}\rfloor+52\lfloor\frac{n+2}{7}\rfloor+51\lfloor\frac{n+3}{7}\rfloor+52\lfloor\frac{n+4}{7}\rfloor+51\lfloor\frac{n+5}{7}\rfloor+52\lfloor\frac{n}{7}\rfloor$

The original sequence $A(n)$ differs from this $a(n)$ base sequence only where $n=7m,m\in ℕ_+$, according to the following bizarre series of differences: $\{7,26,23,53,37,130,52,106,...\}$ for which I have yet to determine a discernible pattern (although searching for the first six with any wildcards in between them does yield [these hits in OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=7%2C__%2C26%2C__%2C23%2C__%2C53%2C__%2C37%2C__%2C130%2C&sort=&language=&go=Search)).

Comment: Hi, could you please edit your question to include [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: Sure I will try. Why are people downvoting the question though?

Comment: Probably because you don't have mathjax.

Comment: Do you want a formula dissimilar from that for your $B(n)?$ While this is a subsequence of the one seen on OEIS, I'm not sure what you may be seeking. Slightly interesting though.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I am wondering if there's a non-recursive or polynomial representation.

Comment: You can always take some finite amount of terms, then take the difference from the $x_{i+1}-x_i$ term, to find a common term, then depending on the number of times you had to do this (i.e, the number of lines your pyramid of numbers create), that tells you the degree of the polynomial to describe this (not sure if you know this method and then what to use if initial conditions). Also, this may be cheap, but there is a $\textit{Mathematica}$ function [FindSequenceFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) if that helps.

Comment: Of course if $7\nmid n$ the smallest non-divisor is $7$, so based on $n \bmod 7$ you have simple formulas such as $A(7k+1)=360k+52$, $A(7k+2)=360k+103$, etc...

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your real question is how to determine the least non-divisor for multiples of $60$.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah I think that seems like one way to describe it. I guess I'm wondering if there's a simplified/polynomial form or diophantine equation to give this sequence. Got some clues from the comments to explore. Sometimes, asking a question helps me understand it better...

Comment: @CommaToast: That is not my area of expertise, so I cannot help you there. – But my suggestion would be to re-write the question (and the title) to make it clear what you are actually looking for. There are many questions “Find a formula for this sequence ...” on this site which lack context and are downvoted and closed quickly. Your question does not fall in that category IMO, but it *may* be that some users react sensitive to the title and downvote before reading all of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I cannot see how to describe your sequence in a single form easily.

However, an excellent linear form is found when one excludes multiples of 420 from the basic form $A(n)=B(60n)$.
Looking at the OEIS sequence bfile through n=10000, this separates your data into 143 main points with 23 to be treated separately.
What results is $A(n)$ ~ $round(K*n)$, where K~ $0.857218087051$, for $n (mod 420) !=0$.  The result is never more than 1 away from the true value.
The remaining 23 points can also be fit with a line (R^2>0.999) but the maximum error is far less satisfactory.  The second coefficient I found for the remnant was ~ 0.883926919519 for $n (mod 420) ==0$.

Comment: Interesting! 857218087051 is a prime number, but it's unclear why 857218087051/10 ought to be related to this sequence. Numbers are so fascinating. As for 420... why should it be special? Truly bizarre.

Comment: See my updated question